# opendatasoft. Analog for 'worldcitiespop' dataset

Tags: data-science, opendatasoft

Who can recommend analog for dateset

> worldcitiespop

on https://public.opendatasoft.com/?

I use this data set early, but now, this data set is not available.

Or may be, you know another open data source  with public api.